# Check video files for integrity

Tags: bash, unix, ffmpeg

I have a library of video files. They get moved around, zipped, unzipped and stuff.

It happened, that some of the files get e.g., transferred/ extracted only partially. This problem usually shows up only when actually watching that video (i.e., the video stops prematurely, which is then really annoying).

Is there a way to batch-verify the integrity of a video library?

I came up with the following, inspired by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4#comment1722682_100290) question:

`find . -regex ".*\.\(avi\|mkv\)" -exec ffmpeg -v error -i {} -f null - \;`

The problem here is, that **ffmpeg does not include the file name when printing the error messages** which means I do not know which file in the batch is erroneous.

To make a long story short:

**Is there a way to include the file name in the ffmpeg error messages?**

Comment: You could store a checksum as part of the filename. If it doesn't match next time you check, the content has changed.

Comment: Add another `-exec` prior to existing one: `-exec echo -n "{}:  " \; -exec ffmpeg.......`  (but it will also print the names of movies without errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply capture the output of `ffmpeg` and print it out with a proper header if not empty:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(avi\|mkv\)" | while read f; do
  ffmpeg_out=$(ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostdin -v error -i "$f" -f null - 2>&1)
  [[ $ffmpeg_out ]] && echo -e "==> ERROR in $f\n${ffmpeg_out}"
done
```

I've added a couple of `ffmpeg` options to ensure proper operations:

- `-hide_banner` turns off the normal FFmpeg preamble, which is just unnecessary noise
- `-nostdin` tells FFmpeg to ignore any (accidental) keyboard interaction